# Unable to Receive Notification from GCM Server after Device Reformat

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a simple Android app that acquires GCM registration token and sends it to a PHP server, for the server to send notification to the app.

Below are my working code:

My RegistrationIntentService class:

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = "RegistrationIntentService";
    private static final String pathToServer = "http://192.168.5.200/phpserverside/registeruser.php";

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        try {
            // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls are local.
            // R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId (the Sender ID) is typically derived from google-services.json.
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
            postData(token);
            // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
            // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
            // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
            // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
            // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }
        // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }


    public static String postData(String token) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        String _response = "";

        String uristr = pathToServer;
        Log.v(TAG, "URI: " + uristr);
        if(uristr!=null){
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpParams params = httpclient.getParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 10000);
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uristr);

            Log.d(TAG, "1 wit username: " + token);
            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registrationId", token));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String bufferedStrChunk = null;

                while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                }
                _response = stringBuilder.toString();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.d(TAG,e.toString());
                _response = "";
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG,e.toString());
                _response = "";
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
            Log.v(TAG, "response: " + _response);
            Log.v("reply of the server: ",_response);
            return _response ;
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

My MyGcmListenerService class:

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        //super.onMessageReceived(from, data);
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
        if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
            // message received from some topic.
        } else {
            // normal downstream message.
        }
        sendNotification(message);
    }
    private void sendNotification(String message) {


        Log.d("MyGcmListenerService", "message: " + message);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                    .setContentTitle("GCM Message Received")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    }
```

And my Manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ictcsu.mybuangproject" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <!-- For checking current network state -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="com.ictcsu.mybuangproject.MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.ictcsu.mybuangproject.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.ictcsu.mybuangproject.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false">
        </service>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The program was working properly on my **Huawei MediaPad 7 Vogue**, however I had to reformat my device for some important reason, and when I re-installed the application it no longer receives any notification.

The reply from my PHP server indicates that it's successful. I also installed the app to my **LG L70** phone and it's properly receiving notifications.

I don't really know what to do, I have searched and tried many codes but it did not work. Do you think that the device reformatting had to do with this?

Comment: Where are u subscribing for the topics?

Comment: I think Multiple login.. with others Registration Id saved for others.. and send noti. to other device...

Comment: I don't know what happens when you reformat device since I have never done it myself, but do the google play services remain or else currently installed? Also I've found that in practice, sometimes even reinstalling the app occasionally cause the GCM service to halt for some time. Usually lasting about 30-60 mins. If that is the case close the question.

Comment: I have been facing this problem since last friday so I guess the the GCM services halting may not be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you reset your device device id changes so the you need to login again so that at server side you can update your device id. Please go through google document to know more about the device id and GCM and how it work it will help to track problem.

Comment: For debugging purposes, I send my registration/device ID to my server every time the user logs in on the app. So I guess the registration ID is not the problem, but I will look up to how the GCM works to solve this problem hopefully.